# ERROR: If this component is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module

Tags: angular, angular-module

I have a reusable component which I'm using inside one of the core module's component and inside a feature module component.
used in `sidenav` nav (part of core module)
I imported it to the core module, However when I try to use it inside a component that is part of the feature module, I got error saying that this component is not part of this module.

my question:
If a component is used in one of the core's modules component and in some of feature modules components, then what module should this `reusable` component be in?

I believe that it should not be a part of the shared-module as it is being used inside the core module, and it should not be in the core module as it is been used in the feature modules.

I tried to import it to the app.module but got the error `If componentName is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module`

**app.module <= imported the component (*also tried to export it*)**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SvgComponent // <- component making the error
  ],
  imports: [
    // core modules
    // .
    // .
    // .
    TrCoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    TutorModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    // services
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports:[SvgComponent],
  // export:[SvgComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

now when I use it inside a featureModule's component or the inside the coreModule's components, I got the error *verify that it is part of this module*

**note that the component is not imported to any other module**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in doubt, make it into a single component angular module (SCAM), the words to search online, and import the component module into any module that uses it. With angular 15 we have standalone components which is an extension of this idea. We can now build full applications without ngmodules.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [AsyncPipe, MatButtonModule], // <----- e.g. anything SvgComponent needs to work
  declarations: [SvgComponent ],
  exports: [SvgComponent ],
})
export class SvgComponentModule {}
```

Comment: Tomas Trajan gave a deep dive on this topic during Peretor 2022 Angular one day event - approx 30 mins https://youtu.be/M65J8pSqU14?t=11217

Comment: Yes. 1. when you add a component to declarations it is available to any other components that share the same "template context", i.e. declared in the same module. 2. when you export a component and import the module the component becomes available to other components in that module. 3. A component declared in a module but not exported is NOT available when the module is imported and is effectively private to the the declaring module.